# Web page layout different on Windows and Linux due to Fonts

Tags: linux, jsf, web, fonts, jboss

We have a web application. The application runs on both Windows and Linux.

On windows, the application works fine (Layout is proper etc.)
On **linux**, the complete layout is **haywire**. **I figured there is a font's problem on Linux.**

On my JSF page, I have specified **Calibri font. I am using JBoss server.**

How can I ensure the layout on windows and linux is identical. I need to eliminate the Fonts problem.

I ***tried installing the Calibri fonts*** on the server, but this becomes a *pre requisite before any installation which surely I would like to avoid..* Infact even after installing I could not notice changes in the layout **(this indicates app failed to read the font).**

Kindly guide.

Is it possible to bundle fonts in JBoss and ship it along with the application. If yes, how can I instruct my application to use fonts present inside JBoss.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@font-face` CSS, as described [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_font-face_rule.asp):

Define a new font, named `myFirstFont`:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

And use it to style an element:

```
.myFirstFontStyledThing {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

This means that the font file must be available from the web. So you either host it in your server (besides your images perhaps - BUT BEWARE THE LICENSING OF THE FONT) or use Google fonts: http://www.google.com/fonts/

Comment: Say suppose I used Calibri font on the elements. But Calibri font by default is not available in Linux. So which font should I use so that both windows and linux can be used. Else is it possible to bundle Fonts in JBoss and ship it with Application. How do I do this if it's possible. Also how do I tell application to use Calibri Fonts from JBoss and not Linux.

Answer (score 0):

if you are defining fonts you are using most probably a css line like that:

```
font-family: Arial, Calibri, sans-serif;
```

css is 'cascading' so in this case if neither arial nor calibri are found sans-serif evaluates to a default sans-serif font on your machine - on Windows - Arial on Mac - Helvetica, on Linux it might be something else.

A good tip would be to use [Google's Fonts](http://www.google.com/fonts) this way you make sure everyone gets the same font and you don't need to install anything on your JBoss and save you some traffic couse it uses CDN!

Comment: This is not what I need. I cannot use Google's fonts. What I want to do is to make my web application work seemlessly on Windows and Linux with no GUI changes.. Font is the only thing which is irking and causing trouble. I cannot use Google Fonts.